# Emission node not rendering at all in Cycles nor Eevee

Tags: shaders, emission

I've been modding this model to use in my animations, and thought it would be cool to add an emission shader to the pupils of the eyes (the model is a robot). I was fine with just having the pupils glow, though I do plan on trying to find a way to condense the light into a laserbeam type style later on, but when I added an emission *node* (not from the principled BSDF), it would not show up at all in the render. Annoyingly, this problem is the same for both Eevee and Cycles:

[image]

Even weirder, as seen by the picture above, the emission clearly is working in the material preview. but look at the picture below, where I go into the rendered preview:

[image]

It does not render. Obviously, this is not just the preview I'm talking about; I'm getting the same results when I hit F12. Like I said, whether it be Cycles or Eevee, I'm still getting the same results, so I do not believe that the render engine is the problem here.
Thinking that it might have just been a problem of that specific material on my eye model here, I opened up a new .blend file with just the default cube (no lights). To that, I added an emission node and turned up the strength to 1000000 (which is, of course, useless, but it effectively demonstrates my point), and checked the rendered preview:

[image]

Same results for both Eevee and Cycles. As one more test, I tried just simply turning on the emission in the Principled BSDF, and was surprised to see that the emission was suddenly working again:

[image]

Not only that, but it was working just as it should in both render engines (showing up in Eevee renders, and actually illuminating surrounding objects in Cycles). This led me to believe that there is a problem with my node setup, not the render engines or anything else.
And I suppose that makes sense; I feel like I'm missing something from my material that is supposed to make the emission work, but I'm not sure what it is. I checked the normals for my mesh, too, but nothing was flipped. I'm not sure what else to do. Can someone please help me with this?

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19OLOnKs4F2CHZ5Y2gCsV-KMPAkh-TNS3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you have the “Shader to RGB” in there? You should connect the output from the Emission Shader directly to the Surface of the Material Output.

Comment: Because each part of the eye is separated by a color ramp (Iris, eye white, pupil, etc), and I specifically want just one part of the eye (the pupil) to emit light. Connect the emission shader directly would cause the entire eye to light up, which is not what I want. Should I attach the .blend file?

Comment: yes, please attach the blend file

Comment: You can use a 'Mix Shader' node to combine mulitple shaders - so the emission only relates to the pupil (or whatever you desire). Yes - probably easiest if someone has your existing material to make changes to better demonstrate.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have any problems accessing it

Comment: You use the emission shader, but then connect it to **Shader to RGB** node. Therefore you only get the information about the color the shader **would** generate. The behavior of the shader is however lost. Now, you take that color and put it into the **Principled BSDF > Base Color** node. You can't see the *base color* without any lightning by design. If you want to **emit** that color again, connect it to the **emission** slot - the one that you changed manually while testing.

Comment: *"the emission clearly is working in the material preview"* - because there's implied lightning in the material preview - but it's not *emission* working, it's normal color being lit up by light.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ohh, I didn't know that! I'm still relatively new to shaders 
I'm a little confused just from an explanation with text, so I'm gonna wait to see if someone can explain this to me in a full answer

Comment: @RichSedman I think I now just realized what you meant, but I have no idea how to implement that (kind of a noob at materials haha). Can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: Guys, I got the thing to work using the B part of the separate RGB (which separated the pupils) > emission > separate RGB > emission BSDF. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TotalBlenderNoob14 It would be great if you could add an answer to your own question detailing your solution. Let me know if it would also help for me to add an answer using Mix Shader - although it sounds like you've already fixed your problem anyway.

Comment: @RichSedman sure I was just getting to that. It'd be cool if you could add your answer for mix shaders as well, since I didn't need to use those and I'm sure many others and I would find it helpful

Comment: @RichSedman I have another problem though: while it works fine in Eevee, the entire eye lights up in cycles. i suppose it's a step up from before, when it wouldn't work in cycles at all, but I really want just the pupil to glow and I can't figure out how. Do you have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real answer:
Based off the *hints* all the people in the comments were giving me, I came up with an answer to solve the problem for BOTH Eevee and Cycles:

"B" part of RGB separator (in my case, since this separates the pupils) > Color ramp (optional, since I used this just to change the emission color) > Emission > Mix shader (plug the BSDF + Emission node into this) > Output

[image]

Here's the result in Eevee:

[image]

Here's the result in Cycles:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note: the solution I found, for whatever reason, only works in Eevee. So, if anyone has a better answer that also works in Cycles, please share it :D

Thanks to all the people who commented on my question, I figured out that the emission was converted to color and thus wouldn't emit any light. The only way to get the pupil to emit light again was to turn it back into a shader. Here's how I did it:

Take the "B" (in my case) from the separate RGB > Emission (strength) > Shader to RGB > Emission (in the Principled BSDF) (put color to color, not alpha to color)
[image]

Like I said, this only works in Eevee. The result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I won't mark this as the answer if someone has a better one

Comment: *Shader to RGB* node only works in *Eevee*.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ohhh thats annoying >:( Do you have a quick explanation of what I should do so it works in Cycles?